# Drag and Drop actually not performed in UI using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Used actions class to do drag and drop and the result got passed, but drag and drop actually not performed in UI. Why i am facing this problem? any solution for this. (Used Selenium - Java code)

Here is the [site](http://www.seleniumframework.com/Practiceform/) used

[Attached the DOM Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7OY5.png)

Code Below:

```
@Test
public void dragDropElement() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    RemoteWebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
    d.manage().window().maximize();
    d.get("http://www.seleniumframework.com/Practiceform/");
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 20);
    WebElement source = d.findElementById("draga");
    WebElement destination = d.findElementById("dragb");
    Actions b = new Actions(d);
    b.dragAndDrop(source, destination).perform();
    d.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code. It worked for me.

```
driver.get("http://www.seleniumframework.com/Practiceform/");
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement sourceLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("draga"));
WebElement targetLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("dragb"));  

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) { var event = document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\"); event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent, true, true, null); event.dataTransfer = { data: {}, setData: function (key, value) { this.data[key] = value; }, getData: function (key) { return this.data[key]; } }; return event; } function dispatchEvent(element, event, transferData) { if (transferData !== undefined) { event.dataTransfer = transferData; } if (element.dispatchEvent) { element.dispatchEvent(event); } else if (element.fireEvent) { element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event); } } function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, target) { var dragStartEvent = createEvent('dragstart'); dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent); var dropEvent = createEvent('drop'); dispatchEvent(target, dropEvent, dragStartEvent.dataTransfer); var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend'); dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent, dropEvent.dataTransfer); } var elementToDrag = arguments[0]; var target = arguments[1]; simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(elementToDrag, target);",
    sourceLocator, targetLocator);
Thread.sleep(5000);
```